# Annotate a mutating function default param

Tags: python, mypy

Let's say I have this function:

```py
def foo(inp = None):
    if inp is None: 
        inp = []
    inp.append("a")
    print(inp)
```

Note:  `None` as default param must be used to avoid updating the same list.

I want to annotate the `inp` param  which is `None` but is going to become a list..I tried something like:

```py
def foo(inp: None = None):
    if inp is None: 
        # this will be flagged as error by type checker, e.g. mypy
        inp: list[int] = [] 
    inp.append("a")
    print(inp)
```

But that won't work because the inp type was already defined as None. What is the recommended  way of doing this?

Comment: `inp: list[int] | None = None` should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`typing.Union`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union) (or `|` shorthand since python >= 3.10) for hinting at several types.

And the synonym for `Union[X, None]` (or `X | None`) is [`typing.Optional`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional)

Arguably most idiomatic overall.

```py
def foo(inp: Optional[list[int]] = None):
    if inp is None: 
        inp = [] 
    inp.append("a")  # NOTE: this will anger mypy as "a" is not int
    print(inp)
```

Most idiomatic (and shortest) since python 3.10 (I favour this one).

```py
def foo(inp: list[int] | None = None):
    if inp is None: 
        inp = [] 
    inp.append("a")  # NOTE: this will anger mypy as "a" is not int
    print(inp)
```

Least idiomatic:

```py
def foo(inp: Union[list[int], None] = None):
    if inp is None: 
        inp = [] 
    inp.append("a")  # NOTE: this will anger mypy as "a" is not int
    print(inp)
```

Comment: I believe `Optional` is more idiomatic than `Union` for this.

Comment: Right, yes, it's synonym with `Union[..., None]` anyway, but I'll add it.

Comment: `| None` will also work in Python 3.7+ with `from __future__ import annotations`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo you're right, all type hints will work with any version of python given postponed evaluation.

Comment: @ljmc thanks, I prefer the second solution too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Optional` type:

```
def foo(inp: Optional[list] = None) -> 'your return type here':
```

For more details, see Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional).